# Assembled two arrays with mdadm with same characteristics in the disks but ended up with slightly different sizes

Tags: mdadm, raid5, sector-size

I'm having problems with the size of the arrays created by mdadm.
First of all, some context. I've recently upgraded from ubuntu server 18.04 to 20.04. I'm running several raid5 arrays and a raid10. Two of them are going to be the subject for this question.
I'm running two raid5 arrays with 4 active "devices" (partitions actually) and one spare.
The raids are named md5 and md6.
After the upgrade one of the disks broke but md5 and md6 acted differently. On md5 kicked in the spare, rebuilding itself, while md6 showed that one of the devices were removed but the spare didn´t kicked in. It had to be re-created by hand.

To summarize, md5 and md6 has the same amount of disk and the partitions are sized the same. Prior to the upgrade and the disk failure md5 and md6 had the same size as well. After the upgrade and disk failure md6 had to be re-created from scratch and ended up with different size. md5 was created with server version 18.04 and md6 with server version 20.04.

Here are the details.

Output of : `lsblk --fs`

```
sda
├─sda1
├─sda2  linux_raid_member (none):5       3c2fa5c0-42a9-e54c-7487-7dbc38986eaf
│ └─md5 ext4              FSROOT1        446d8ccf-08ea-4300-8d9e-72cf4606966a  221.6G     5% /
├─sda3  linux_raid_member salto-server:6 fbc8430b-64d7-8d34-b54f-6c4626505783
│ └─md6 ext4                             acb4b5ec-7ad6-476c-951e-3f12e6a2b3cf
├─sda4  linux_raid_member ubuntu:7       a6a7101e-539e-1310-1f8e-1d6af62327a6
│ └─md7 ext4              FDDATA1        9c42781d-cb8a-4061-ac43-13fbf24f40e3    1.6T    35% /mnt/r5d2
├─sda5  linux_raid_member salto-server:4 a7ef9f85-e156-fc26-1aff-66d7eec302c9
│ └─md4 swap              SWAP           09a58a47-0ca0-452d-ac72-d09c3e198c11                [SWAP]
└─sda6  linux_raid_member ubuntu:8       9f6decc2-851b-6c29-ac65-4940b7a4d4c5
  └─md8 ext4              FDDATA2        6c8dc3b0-3e23-4268-8b33-bb6d106b0d44    1.5T    64% /mnt/r5d3
sdb
├─sdb1
├─sdb2  linux_raid_member (none):5       3c2fa5c0-42a9-e54c-7487-7dbc38986eaf
│ └─md5 ext4              FSROOT1        446d8ccf-08ea-4300-8d9e-72cf4606966a  221.6G     5% /
├─sdb3  linux_raid_member salto-server:6 fbc8430b-64d7-8d34-b54f-6c4626505783
│ └─md6 ext4                             acb4b5ec-7ad6-476c-951e-3f12e6a2b3cf
├─sdb4  linux_raid_member ubuntu:7       a6a7101e-539e-1310-1f8e-1d6af62327a6
│ └─md7 ext4              FDDATA1        9c42781d-cb8a-4061-ac43-13fbf24f40e3    1.6T    35% /mnt/r5d2
├─sdb5  linux_raid_member salto-server:4 a7ef9f85-e156-fc26-1aff-66d7eec302c9
│ └─md4 swap              SWAP           09a58a47-0ca0-452d-ac72-d09c3e198c11                [SWAP]
└─sdb6  linux_raid_member ubuntu:8       9f6decc2-851b-6c29-ac65-4940b7a4d4c5
  └─md8 ext4              FDDATA2        6c8dc3b0-3e23-4268-8b33-bb6d106b0d44    1.5T    64% /mnt/r5d3
sdc
├─sdc1
├─sdc2  linux_raid_member (none):5       3c2fa5c0-42a9-e54c-7487-7dbc38986eaf
│ └─md5 ext4              FSROOT1        446d8ccf-08ea-4300-8d9e-72cf4606966a  221.6G     5% /
├─sdc3  linux_raid_member salto-server:6 fbc8430b-64d7-8d34-b54f-6c4626505783
│ └─md6 ext4                             acb4b5ec-7ad6-476c-951e-3f12e6a2b3cf
├─sdc4  linux_raid_member ubuntu:7       a6a7101e-539e-1310-1f8e-1d6af62327a6
│ └─md7 ext4              FDDATA1        9c42781d-cb8a-4061-ac43-13fbf24f40e3    1.6T    35% /mnt/r5d2
├─sdc5  linux_raid_member salto-server:4 a7ef9f85-e156-fc26-1aff-66d7eec302c9
│ └─md4 swap              SWAP           09a58a47-0ca0-452d-ac72-d09c3e198c11                [SWAP]
└─sdc6  linux_raid_member ubuntu:8       9f6decc2-851b-6c29-ac65-4940b7a4d4c5
  └─md8 ext4              FDDATA2        6c8dc3b0-3e23-4268-8b33-bb6d106b0d44    1.5T    64% /mnt/r5d3
sdd
├─sdd1
├─sdd2  linux_raid_member (none):5       3c2fa5c0-42a9-e54c-7487-7dbc38986eaf
│ └─md5 ext4              FSROOT1        446d8ccf-08ea-4300-8d9e-72cf4606966a  221.6G     5% /
├─sdd3  linux_raid_member salto-server:6 fbc8430b-64d7-8d34-b54f-6c4626505783
│ └─md6 ext4                             acb4b5ec-7ad6-476c-951e-3f12e6a2b3cf
├─sdd4  linux_raid_member ubuntu:7       a6a7101e-539e-1310-1f8e-1d6af62327a6
│ └─md7 ext4              FDDATA1        9c42781d-cb8a-4061-ac43-13fbf24f40e3    1.6T    35% /mnt/r5d2
├─sdd5  linux_raid_member salto-server:4 a7ef9f85-e156-fc26-1aff-66d7eec302c9
│ └─md4 swap              SWAP           09a58a47-0ca0-452d-ac72-d09c3e198c11                [SWAP]
└─sdd6  linux_raid_member ubuntu:8       9f6decc2-851b-6c29-ac65-4940b7a4d4c5
  └─md8 ext4              FDDATA2        6c8dc3b0-3e23-4268-8b33-bb6d106b0d44    1.5T    64% /mnt/r5d3
```

Here is the conformation of the devices.

`cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md4 : active raid10 sda5[0] sdd5[3] sdc5[2] sdb5[1]
      9754624 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]

md6 : active raid5 sda3[0] sdd3[4] sdc3[2] sdb3[1]
      263473152 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

md8 : active raid5 sdd6[6] sda6[0] sdc6[5] sdb6[4]
      5318710272 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/14 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md7 : active raid5 sdd4[6] sda4[0] sdc4[5] sdb4[4]
      2929293312 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 3/8 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

md5 : active raid5 sdd2[6] sda2[0] sdc2[5] sdb2[4]
      263476224 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

**Please note at this step that md6 and md5 are showing different amount of blocks.**

Here is the size of the devices

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd[a-d][2,3]`

```
Disk /dev/sda2: 83.84 GiB, 90000326656 bytes, 175781888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda3: 83.84 GiB, 90000326656 bytes, 175781888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb2: 83.84 GiB, 90000326656 bytes, 175781888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb3: 83.84 GiB, 90000326656 bytes, 175781888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc2: 83.84 GiB, 90000326656 bytes, 175781888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc3: 83.84 GiB, 90000326656 bytes, 175781888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd2: 83.84 GiB, 90000326656 bytes, 175781888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd3: 83.84 GiB, 90000326656 bytes, 175781888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

For redundancy, here is the the output of fdisk on md5 and md6

`fdisk -l /dev/md[5,6]`

```
Disk /dev/md5: 251.28 GiB, 269799653376 bytes, 526952448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1572864 bytes


Disk /dev/md6: 251.27 GiB, 269796507648 bytes, 526946304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1572864 bytes
```

Maybe there is something that I'm missing or some option hidden. But I'm sure that both arrays were created with the same commands.
It seems like different versions of mdadm crated slightly different array sizes.

Is there a way to know where the difference lay? And maybe to re-build md6 to match md5?
I cannot touch md5 as is the / but md6 was the backup and i can do as i please with it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The version of mdadm running on the server is:
`mdadm - v4.1 - 2018-10-01`

Comment: you can add that as an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1410184/edit) to your original question. We prefer that important information not be left only in comments, which can be deleted or moved at any time.